Slow Ansible installation of cron jobs
I have a variable defined like this:
cron_jobs:
  - name: "check dirs 1"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "5,2"
    job: "ls -alh > /dev/null"
  - name: "check dirs 2"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "3,4"
    job: "ls -alh > /dev/null"
  ...

I want to create cron jobs based on this variable. So, I create an Ansible task that looks like this:
    - name: "Install cron jobs"
      ansible.builtin.cron:
        name: "{{ item.name }}"
        minute: "{{ item.minute }}"
        hour: "{{ item.hour }}"
        job: "{{ item.job }}"
      loop: "{{ cron_jobs }}"

It works. The problem, however, is that it takes around 5 seconds to process each item, and the variable has hundreds or thousands of items.
I've seen in this post that it is possible to use a crontab file to manage all cron jobs. I don't want to use this approach, however, as manually-entered crontab entries might get accidentally deleted and would need to be manually re-entered. There are a lot of users in the managed server, so users might eventually manually enter new cron jobs without using Ansible.
Is there a way to rewrite the task so that it won't take minutes or hours to install the cron jobs?

Your Use Case could be addressed/solved by using template or copy and placing cron files under /etc/cron.d.

I would first investigate the reason why I need to declare thousands of cron entries on a server has this just seem totally outrageous. Next, once I went down to something that seems more sensible, I'd investigate why it takes five seconds to declare one cron. My current experience is rather below one second. As a non-exhaustive question to possibly put you on track, is Ansible using master sessions and/or pipe-lining?

@Zeitounator thanks for the tips. how would i know if Ansible is using master sessions and/or pipelining? i haven't defined much variables in my ansible config file except for host_key_checking and interpreter_python.

@U880D thanks for the tips. would manually entered cron jobs be deleted if i create files in /etc/cron.d?

@hermit.crab I suggest you search for "Speed up ansible execution" in your favorite search engine as a start to your ansible optimization journey.

"Would manually entered cron jobs be deleted if i create files in /etc/cron.d?", no. For further reading, Why are folders for configuration files always named *.d, What does the .d stand for in directory names?, Linux configuration: Understanding *.d directories in /etc, Many directories have a .d suffix/extension. What does it mean?
